# Bar fight: would Superman's moral code allow him to take vengeance like that?

Tags: superman, man-of-steel

In the 2013 Man of Steel, Superman stops a lout from abusing a waitress. The lout pours beer over him and then pushes him and discovers that he is actually supernaturally solid but throws a can at Superman's head anyway (which really does not make sense). We know that Superman is not allowed to actually injure a human (although he does sort of in a similar scene in one of the Reeve movies after he gets his powers back -- presumably he caused no permanent harm).

The lout does find his truck inexplicably completely destroyed which he would have no way of knowing had been done by the guy he had abused. But would Superman's code even allow this kind of property destruction?

Comment: "*We know that Superman is not allowed to actually injure a human*" - Huh? Says who?

Comment: @Valorum: I know for sure he can't kill a human -- what kind of injury is he allowed to inflict?

Comment: He does [occasionally kill humans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=185&v=F0MRaLVATJ8&feature=emb_title) and he's more than happy to hurt criminals and such

Answer (score 3):

According to the film's [official novelisation](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Man_of_Steel:_The_Official_Movie_Novelization), Superman's "moral compass" is sufficiently human as to not only allow him to trash the guy's rig (in revenge for getting him fired and his inappropriate advances to the waitress) but to then *revel in thought of the trucker finding his rig in pieces*.

> **He smiled for a moment, imagining Ludlow’s reaction when he saw what
> was left of his eighteen-wheeler.** Then he put The Bearcat behind him
> and kept on hiking north... toward Ellesmere Island. The conversation
> he’d overheard in the bar played over and over again in his mind.